# Zeppelin cannot start

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am trying to install Zeppelin, I did setup SPARK, JAVA home in `/conf/`. I also changed the port to not be conflict with Spark's port. But when I start `zeppelin-daemon` here what I got:

```
Log dir doesn't exist, create /opt/zeppelin-0.8.2/zeppelin-0.8.2-bin-all/logs
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/zeppelin-0.8.2/zeppelin-0.8.2-bin-all/logs’: Permission denied
Pid dir doesn't exist, create /opt/zeppelin-0.8.2/zeppelin-0.8.2-bin-all/run
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/zeppelin-0.8.2/zeppelin-0.8.2-bin-all/run’: Permission denied
/opt/zeppelin-0.8.2/zeppelin-0.8.2-bin-all/bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh: line 187: /opt/zeppelin-0.8.2/zeppelin-0.8.2-bin-all/logs/zeppelin-harry-Harry-SNS.out: No such file or directory
Zeppelin start                                             [  OK  ]
/opt/zeppelin-0.8.2/zeppelin-0.8.2-bin-all/bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh: line 196: /opt/zeppelin-0.8.2/zeppelin-0.8.2-bin-all/run/zeppelin-harry-Harry-SNS.pid: No such file or directory
/opt/zeppelin-0.8.2/zeppelin-0.8.2-bin-all/bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh: line 189: /opt/zeppelin-0.8.2/zeppelin-0.8.2-bin-all/logs/zeppelin-harry-Harry-SNS.out: No such file or directory
cat: /opt/zeppelin-0.8.2/zeppelin-0.8.2-bin-all/run/zeppelin-harry-Harry-SNS.pid: No such file or directory
Zeppelin process died                                      [FAILED]
```

as I understand, its missing `pid` directory which idk how can I create one.

Comment: Looks like a permission problem. Please run with root privileges `chown -R USER /opt/zeppelin-0.8.2/`. Replace USER with the username who runs zeppelin.

Comment: Cool! Thats one of the reason. I finally solved it! Thanks